# Dropdown slideToggle if click anywhere except element that are cursor:pointer

Tags: onclick, cursor, dropdown

So, i got a fancy dropdown that i want to slide back if clicks anywhere except on elements that are cursor:pointer..If you can understand me..

Currently I got this code:

```
$("html").click(function() {
   if($(".user-dropdown").is(':visible')) {
      $(".user-dropdown").slideToggle('fast');
   }
});
```

Comment: Could you share the fiddle?

Comment: @pratikwebdev https://jsfiddle.net/hzgknrd0/

Comment: It seem to be working fine. Drowdown is sliding back when user clicks on other than dropdown items. You want to exclude top icon?

Comment: @pratikwebdev I don't have any problems all is good..I just ask if i can make it slide if you click outside dropdown but the element isnt on cursor:pointer;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply verify the `cursor type` of element triggering event if its not `pointer` then slideback.

```
$("html").click(function() {
    var cursorType =  $(this).css('cursor');
   if(cursorType!="pointer")
   {
       if($(".user-dropdown").is(':visible')) {
          $(".user-dropdown").slideToggle('fast');
        }
   }
});
```

Try it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: Didn't worked that, but i did this and now works:
$("html").click(function(e) {
   if($(e.target).css('cursor') != 'pointer') {
      //code
   }
});

Thank you for help!